# ragne slider bubble fails to move with slider movement

Tags: javascript

I have created a range slider where I am displaying a bubble with slider value within it.

( This example is based on https://css-tricks.com/value-bubbles-for-range-inputs/, I am simply attempted to recreate based on JS)

Here is a function that is suppose to make the bubble move along with the slider:

```
function displayValue(event) {
  var rangeInput = document.getElementById('myRange');
  var width = rangeInput.offsetWidth;

  var min = rangeInput.getAttribute('min');
  var max = rangeInput.getAttribute('max');

  var newPoint = (event.target.value - min)/(max - min);

  var offset = -1.3;

  var newPlace;
  if (newPoint < 0) {
    newPlace = 0;
  } else if (newPoint > 1 ) {
    newPlace = width;
  } else  {
    newPlace = width * newPoint + offset;
    offset -= newPoint;

  }

  var outputElement = document.getElementById('myOutput');  
  outputElement.value = event.target.value;
  outputElement.style.left = newPlace;
  outputElement.style.marginLeft = offset = "%";


}
```

This function only partially works (as in the value insider the bubble updates but not the position)

Why is the sldier failing to update it's position ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/lt99U0uvMkPsibY54GAU

Answer (score 0):

I found couple of anomalies in your code which might be typos.

Instead of:

```
outputElement.style.left = newPlace;
outputElement.style.marginLeft = offset = "%";
```

Try:

```
outputElement.style.left = newPlace + 'px';
outputElement.style.marginLeft = offset + "%";
```